# Error when running a working macro from a Ribbon

Tags: vba, excel

Below is a macro for Excel2010 in VBA. It's working only when I open VBA Code editor and run from the menu Debug. I tried to put it to Ribbon and run it from there but I've got this error:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Additionally, when I change all `Range()` into `.Worksheet(i).Range()`, the procedure does not run at all with the same error. It's like .Range does not seem to be part of Worksheet(i). I have no experience in Excel 2010 VBA.

```
Sub CopyAndRearrange()
    Dim ns As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ns = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ns).Cells.ClearContents

    For i = 1 To ns - 1
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .Worksheets(i).Activate
            Range("E1") = CInt(.Worksheets(i).Name)
            Range(Range("G1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 7)) = "=IF(RC[-6]=0,"""",RC[-6] + R4C5"
            Range(Range("I1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 8)) = "=RC[-6]"

            Range(Range("G1"), Range("I1").End(xlDown)).Copy
            Sheets(ns).Activate
            If i = 1 Then
                'Range(Range("G1"), Range("I1").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(ns).Range("A1")
                Sheets(ns).Range("A1").Select
            Else
                'Range(Range("G1"), Range("I1").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(ns).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
                Sheets(ns).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    Next
    Sheets(ns).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

---

EDIT:
OK. I have slightly changed the code in hope I was wrong about referring to the right sheet etc. The problem is still there. The line: `ActiveSheet.Range(rg1, rg1) = "=IF(RC[-6]=0,"""",RC[-6] + R4C5"` causes the problem. Surprisingly, it is not the first that I refer to Range in the an active sheet and for some reasons, I really don't know why, I've got the error!!! To exhaust all possibilities, I have also tried these:

- Explicitly re-create a Module in VBA Window
- Re-open the file
- Record a macro and insert a code in there

Nothing's worked so far. I have given up but maybe someone in future will see the problem and give a solution here.

```
Public Sub CopyAndRearrange()
    Dim ns As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rg1 As Range
    Dim rg2 As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ns = wb.Worksheets.Count
    wb.Sheets(ns).Cells.ClearContents

    For i = 1 To ns - 1
        With wb
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(i)
            ws.Activate

            ActiveSheet.Range("E1") = CInt(ActiveSheet.Name)

            Set rg1 = ActiveSheet.Range("G1")
            Set rg2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 7)
            ActiveSheet.Range(rg1, rg1) = "=IF(RC[-6]=0,"""",RC[-6] + R4C5"

            Set rg1 = ActiveSheet.Range("I1")
            Set rg2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 8)
            ActiveSheet.Range(rg1, rg2) = "=RC[-6]"

            Set rg1 = ActiveSheet.Range("G1")
            Set rg2 = ActiveSheet.Range("I1").End(xlDown)
            ActiveSheet.Range(rg1, rg2).Copy

            Sheets(ns).Activate
            If i = 1 Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    Next
    Sheets(ns).Range("A1").Select

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set rg1 = Nothing
    Set rg2 = Nothing
    Set cell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use ThisWorkbook which will refer to the original workbook instead of ActiveWorkbook

Comment: I've changed it. I did not notice the difference. The error is still there. There's something I don't know yet and I try to establish where the problem is but I don't have much experience in Excel VBA. Stack Exchange is Q/A website. I did not do anything wrong here!

I have no idea why I received -2. I have asked the question and have given the example.

Comment: I don't know why you've got -2, anyway +1 from me as a small consolation :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Sub CopyAndRearrange(Control as IRibbionControl)
```

Adding the control allows the code to be executed from the ribbion.

Comment: It's more than that. When I reopened the file today it's failed to work completely.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the answer to my own question.

The problem was missing bracket in this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(rg1, rg1) = "=IF(RC[-6]=0,"""",RC[-6] + R4C5"
```

which should be:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(rg1, rg1) = "=IF(RC[-6]=0,"""",RC[-6] + R4C5)"
```

If the error was more intelligible, I would not lose 2 days to look for this problem :/